How can we make torch.frombuffer support torch.compile?
I have a python function like below:
def custom_rgb2tensor(binary):
    t_image = torch.frombuffer(binary,dtype=torch.uint8)
    img = cv_imdecode(t_image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img_tensor = torch.from_numpy(img[:, :, ::-1].copy()).unsqueeze(0) / 255.0
    return img_tensor

I tried many ways to make it compilable with torch.compile, but got error below:
File "/root/butterfly/ComfyUI/env_wl/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/fx/proxy.py", line 298, in create_arg
    raise NotImplementedError(f"argument of type: {type(a)}")
torch._dynamo.exc.InternalTorchDynamoError: argument of type: <class 'bytes'>

from user code:
   File "/root/butterfly/ComfyUI/./custom_nodes/ComfyUI-Optimus/compilable/op_compilable.py", line 73, in custom_rgb2tensor
    t_image = torch.frombuffer(binary,dtype=torch.uint8)

Does anyone have a good idea?
If I remove the torch.compile annotation, it works fine.
